# gcc: __attribute__ for enum members

Tags: c, gcc, enums, clang

GNU gcc and clang gcc can't agree on whether this code is valid or not.
Which one has the bug?

With clang:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix

$ echo 'enum {a = 1, b __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.10))) = 1};' | /usr/bin/gcc -c -xc -
(no output, it works)
```

With GNU gcc:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2

$ echo 'enum {a = 1, b __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.10))) = 1};' | gcc -c -xc -
<stdin>:1:16: error: expected ',' or '}' before '__attribute__'
```

For those that must know why in the world I might care, there's an [upstream bug in sagemath](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/18254#comment:42).

---

It looks like this is explicitly a clang extension, so maybe the fault is with whoever put that in the C headers.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#attributes-on-enumerators

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerator attributes in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726340/enumerator-attributes-in-gcc)

Comment: For others stumbling upon this question without reading it, make sure the `= 1` comes after the `__attribute__` call, not before it!