# Enumerator attributes in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, enums

GCC's [online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Enumerator-Attributes.html) claims it supports enumerator attributes:

> GCC allows attributes to be set on enumerators.

It then gives a code example using such attributes:

```
 enum E {
   oldval __attribute__((deprecated)),
   newval
 };

 int
 fn (void)
 {
   return oldval;
 }
```

But when I try it on my GCC (4.8.4), I get an error:

```
t.c:2:15: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘}’ before ‘__attribute__’
        oldval __attribute__((deprecated)),
               ^
```

Do I need to enable them somewhere? Or use a different GCC?

Note that Clang also claims to support this C extension, but with Clang it works as expected.

Comment: Looks like [the head revision of gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qfb434eH2jV4bIET) accepts this

Comment: GCC 5.2 fails with the same message. It looks to me like a bug in GCC or in the documentation (maybe they are no longer supported but they forgot to update the docs).

Comment: I correct myself. it looks like it is a new development, and you are looking at the online docs for the _bleeding_ version. See [here the patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-05/msg00475.html) that implements it on May-2015. If you look at the [documentation for your GCC version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax), you will not find it!

Comment: Note, any compiler that supports any sort of attribute there should support the C++11 `[[attribute]]` syntax. This applies to enumerators in the upcoming C++1z standard, but in practice the grammar is [applied](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AeobTL2hqL5aFOrC) [retroactively](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oXdX7Dx8epY1OMON) to older dialects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you are looking at refers to the latest development branch, but if we go to [gcc online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and we look at the [gcc 5.2 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/), which is the latest release, we see no *Enumerator Attributes* section. This explains why it this feature works in the [head revision of gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qfb434eH2jV4bIET) but not older versions.

So this is a relatively new feature that is only available in the head branch and is not part of any other releases(yet). clang seems to [support this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#attributes-on-enumerators) all the way [back in 3.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CeCUcoXLAusIgiGh).